# MPAndroidChart Logarithmic Y Axis

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I need to implement a line chart inside my application and I would like to make use of MPAndroidChart. 
The problem is that the value on the y axis will be somewhere between 1 and 1x10^-12. Thats why i need an Logarithmic view on that axis.

Is there any way to achieve this with that libary? (or maybe other chart libary?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chart library uses `Matrix`-multiplication for value to pixel transformation. **Those are linear-transformations, which means they cannot stretch logarithmically.**

However, with some work on your own, you could modify the values you provide for the chart in a way that they fit into the chart: [Is there a transformation matrix that can scale the x and/or y axis logarithmically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538844/is-there-a-transformation-matrix-that-can-scale-the-x-and-or-y-axis-logarithmically)

Also, you can choose to display whatever you want on the y-axis as labels, by using the `ValueFormatter` interface.

So simply transform the values on the y-axis e.g. from "y" to "10^y".