# MPAndroidChart: make candlestick yVals relative to the data

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). My app shows some market exchange data, and I need it to display the values the way every rise and dip should be noticed. That's how some data looks like now:

[image: Current app look]

You can see that all values except the first one are displayed like dots as they're too small relative to the first one. What I want it to be is like this:

[image: Wanted look]

Here the yValues notice the difference between market values and adjust accordingly. Anyway I could do like that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I understand this, you might think of Y-Axis in logarythmic scale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996941/mpandroidchart-logarithmic-y-axis, which will need transformations on provided data.
Library does not support this out -of-the-box.